# How do I rigorously show that $f(x, y) = \frac{x}{2|x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|}}$ is continuous when $x, y \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

For the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous, I need to show that for some given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that if $||z - z'|| < \delta$, then $|f(z) - f(z')| < \epsilon$.

Here's what I tried. Let $z = (x, y)$ and $z' = (x', y')$ where $||z - z'|| < \delta$. Then (sorry the formatting is a bit cramped)

\begin{align}
|f(z) - f(z')|
&= \left| \frac{x}{2|x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|}} - \frac{x'}{2|x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|}}\right| \\\\
&= \left| \frac{x |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} - x' |x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|}}{2|x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|}}\right| \\\\
&\leq \left| x |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} - x' |x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} \right| \\\\
&\leq \left| x |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} \right| + \left|x' |x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} \right| \\\\
&= |xx'| \left| \sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} + \sqrt{|x|+|y|}\right|
\end{align}

but then I get stuck. I know that

\begin{align}
||z - z'||
&= \sqrt{(x - x')^2 + (y - y')^2} \\
&\leq |x - x'| + |y - y'| \\
&\leq |x| + |x'| + |y| + |y'|
\end{align}

but I'm not sure how to use that to find some $\delta$ that only depends on $\epsilon, x$, and $x'$.

Comment: Expand $|x| + |x'| + |y| + |y'|$. On what variable does $\delta$ depend on?

Comment: Since you don't have to deal with continuity with $x=0$ or $y=0$, you can study the four cases $x<0<y$, $x,y<0$, $0<x,y$ and $y<0<x$ and get rid of the absolute values. You will then study simpler functions.

Comment: @Nickolas $\delta$ depends on $z = (x, y)$, so do I need to rely on the fact that $|x - y| \leq ||z - z'|| < \delta$? Or are you referring to the cases that Martigan mentioned?

Comment: @Nickolas To clarify, I guess I'm not 100% sure on how to "expand" $|x| + |x'| + |y| + |y'|$, unless you mean using the fact that $x' = x + h_1$ and $y' = y + h_2$ where $h_1, h_2 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Michael $ \sqrt{(x - x')^2 + (y - y')^2} = | (x,y) - (x',y')| < \epsilon$

Comment: Proving, or acknowledging that (someone else)/(a book) proved that sums, products, quotients (where denominator $\neq 0$) maintain continuity, and then applying that to this case is just as rigorous as an epsilon-delta proof, by the way (but I assume the exercise is to use epsilon-delta).

Comment: @GPerez I thought that might be the case, but since I'm working through an analysis book, I'm trying to use epsilon-delta proofs wherever possible. I should be able to prove that the quotient of continuous functions is continuous using epsilon-delta, though. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Michael Actually I think the proof of the properties I mention is easier than proving continuity for this particular function.

Comment: @Michael I provided identification of the areas that the proof went astray along with a prototype of an $\epsilon -\delta$ proof.  Please let me know how I can improve the answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorems are made for that.

In order to show that your $f$ is continuous the simplest and more rigorous proof is to show:

Lemma 1) composition of continuous functions is continuous

Lemma 2) product of continuous functions is continuous

Lemma 3) sum of continuous functions is continuous

Lemma 4) constant, $\sqrt x$ and $|x|$ are continuous functions

Lemma 5) the reciproque of a never vanishing continuous function is continuous

Then the continuity of $f$ easily follows from these lemmata and each one is much easier to prove than the continuity of your original $f$.

Answer (score 1):

User126154 has succinctly and eloquently provided the mathematically mature way forward.

Here, we will illustrate (1) two points at which the proof in the posted question went astray, and (2) one way forward using a "brute force," $\epsilon-\delta$ approach.

---

In the original posted question, the first point at which the proof went astray occurs at the inequality 
$$
\left| \frac{x |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} - x' |x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|}}{2|x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|}}\right| 
\leq \left| x |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|} - x' |x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} \right|
$$

In general, this inequality $2|x|\sqrt{|x|+|y|} |x'|\sqrt{|x'|+|y'|}\ge 1$  need not hold.  In fact, this term can be arbitrarily small.

The second point at which the proof went astray occurs at the application of the triangle inequality.  While the statement is correct, application of the triangle inequality provides a gross overestimate.  This overestimate does not provide a viable way forward toward proving continuity.

---

So, how does one proceed in a "brute force" way.  We will look at a simpler problem that will provide the prototype to handle the  problem of interest.

Let's show that $1/\sqrt{x}$ is continuous for $x> 0$.  To that end, we write

$$\begin{align}
\left|1/\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x_0}\right|&=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x_0}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x_0}}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{x-x_0}{x_0\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x_0}}\right|
\end{align}$$

Here, we enforce the following.  We will restrict $0<|x-x_0|<a x_0$, where $0<a<1$.  For example, let's choose $a=1/2$ (the choice is arbitrary).  Then, note that

$$\frac{1}{x_0\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x_0}}<1/x_0^{3/2}$$

Using this inequality reveals that for fixed $x_0>0$, given $\epsilon >0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|1/\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x_0}\right|&\le \left|\frac{x-x_0}{x_0^{3/2}}\right|\\\\
&< \epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-x_0|< x_0^{3/2}\epsilon$.  Now, let us choose $\delta =\min(x_0^{3/2}\epsilon , x_0/2)$.  Then, for any fixed $x_0>0$, for all $\epsilon >0$, we have

$$\left|1/\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x_0}\right| < \epsilon$$

whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta =\min(x_0^{3/2}\epsilon , x_0/2)$

This same approach can be used to the problem of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Define $L_m$ by {(x, mx); m real} and take all the sequences ($x_n$,$y_n$) converging to ($x_0$,$y_0$) each of them following the paralelle route of some $L_m$. Then f(($x_n$,$y_n$)) converges to f(($x_0$,$y_0$)) for all of these sequences . It is enough.